# Python | Keras | Prediction with Multiple Variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prediction

I have a data-set with 3 columns.

```
|Date    |Price      |Sentiment   |
|---------------------------------|
|Date 1  |Price 1    |S1          |
|------------------------- -------| 
|Date 2  |Price 2    |S2          |
|------------------------- -------| 
|Date 3  |Price 3    |S3          |
|------------------------- -------|
```

In this data-set the 'Price' depends on the 'Sentiment' values, i.e. if the sentiment value is positive the price will increase or it will decrease otherwise. 
I need to predict the 'Price' using Keras. Right now I use the code from [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) to predict the 'Price' but it is not considering the 'Sentiment' values for prediction.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

# load the dataset
dataframe = read_csv('./dataset/combined.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
print (dataset)
dataset = dataset.astype('float64')

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 3
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(look_back, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)

# invert predictions
print (trainPredict)
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

# calculate root mean squared error
#trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
#print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
#testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
#print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))

# shift train predictions for plotting
trainPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
trainPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
trainPredictPlot[look_back:len(trainPredict)+look_back, :] = trainPredict

# shift test predictions for plotting
testPredictPlot = numpy.empty_like(dataset)
testPredictPlot[:, :] = numpy.nan
testPredictPlot[len(trainPredict)+(look_back*2)+1:len(dataset)-1, :] = testPredict

# plot baseline and predictions
plt.plot(scaler.inverse_transform(dataset))
plt.plot(trainPredictPlot)
plt.plot(testPredictPlot)
plt.show()
```

How can I predict the 'Price' by considering both 'Price' and 'Sentiment' columns?

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing to do would be to actually load the relevant column, so change

```
dataframe = read_csv('./dataset/combined.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python')
```

to

```
dataframe = read_csv('./dataset/combined.csv', usecols=[1, 2], engine='python')
```

I don't see the columns being referenced explicitly so I think that should be enough, but I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: That leads to this error, 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "complex_prediction.py", line 60, in <module>
    trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
  File "C:\Users\nidhi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 385, in inverse_transform
    X -= self.min_
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (490,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (490,2)'